# Drupal: How do I create a function based on the language, so that it will not display entities?

Tags: php, drupal, multilingual

Sorry for my english
I'am trying to build a multilingual-site. I followed a tutorial to that matter on youtube. It's very good. It guides you through the jungle of setting all these modules and settings. But what he doesn't cover is a solution for the ouput based on the view-module.

I tried searching around but there seems to be no solution on how to get the views-module displaying the correct language based on the language. Everything else is switched correctly by choosing a language.

Ok, so I was thinking:
Under View-Edit in the Advanced section, I saw the option FIELD-LANGUAGE. By Default it's set to CURRENT-USER-LANGUAGE. I changed it to DEFAULT-SITE-LANGUAGE. This causes the affect, that the view displays every language,the default and it's translated version. 
Now, if i would create an function, that will unset the content when choosing a language, all would be good. Now what i found out so far is: I printed out a DSM($variables['view'] on the template_preprocess-views-view level. And under RESULTS, i see the two objects, the representation of the default and the translated version. I could use the string-value from node_language of an object so it should display or not bassed on the language. But since I'am not an guru in PHP I don't know how to proceed further. 
I'am thinking of writing a function on the html level and retrieve the particular value of it's classes_array, when it's in english mode the value will be: i18n-en. So bassed on the value I will unset those objects that I don't want to display under the views view result. But how can I pass the behaviour to view, or is this after all the correct way? 
Well, I hope you all have enough patient understanding my issue.
thanks a lot in advance.
Marcel

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you want to achieve.

You always have global object $language and you can check current language something like:

```
if ($language->language == 'en') do something language dependent...
```

And when you edit the view you can create language contextual filter, calculate language you need from PHP and use views_embed_view() or views_get_view_results() with passing language to limit results to one (or more) language.